# AngularJS filter infinite loop

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I've written a filter in AngularJS, which was working fine when using it with ng-options on an input select.
Since I needed a more powerful select box with additional functionality, I've written a directive.

The directive has an isolated scope with the **filtered** options being passed via a two-way binding. Unfortunately, my filter produces a "10 $digest() iterations reached"-error.

This is my filter:

```
angularAMD.filter('gasUsableInSpacer', function(){
            return function(gasTypes, isSealed) {

                var filtered = [];

                angular.forEach(gasTypes, function(gasType){
                    if(isSealed){
                        if(gasType.usableInSealedSpacer)
                            filtered.push(gasType);
                    }
                    if(!isSealed){
                        if(gasType.usableInSecondarySpacer)
                            filtered.push(gasType);
                    }
                });
                return filtered;
            };
        });
```

and this is how I included my directive:

```
<filter-select options="allGasTypes | gasUsableInSpacer:element.sealed" element="element.gasType" id="gasTypeX"></filter-select>
```

The above way isn't working, while this is working fine:

```
<select class="form-control" ng-model="element.gasType" ng-options="gasType as gasType.naturalName for gasType in allGasTypes | gasUsableInSpacer:element.sealed track by gasType.id" name="gasTypeX" id="gasTypeX">
</select>
```

This is my directives controller:

```
angularAMD.directive("filterSelect", function (angularLoad) {
            return {
                templateUrl: 'rmlModMainApp/directives/filterSelect.html',
                restrict: 'E',
                scope: {
                    options : '=',
                    element: '='
                },
                link: function(scope, element, attr) {

                    angularLoad.loadCSS(requirejs.toUrl('rmlModMainApp/directives/filterSelect.css'));
                    scope.listVisible = false;

                    scope.selectOption = function(option){
                        scope.element = option;
                        scope.toggleList();
                    };

                    scope.toggleList = function(){
                        scope.listVisible = !scope.listVisible;
                    }
                }
            }
        });
    });
```

And the part of the view that is supposed to render the options:

```
<div class="filterSelect">
    <div class="filterSelectContent" ng-show="listVisible">
        <form class="filterSelectSearch">
            <div class="input-group col-xs-12">
                <input type="text" class="form-control" id="filterText" ng-model="search.text" placeholder="filter" ng-model-options="{debounce: {'default':500, 'blur':0}}">
                <span class="input-group-addon"><i class="fa fa-lg fa-filter"></i></span>
            </div>
        </form>
        <div class="filterSelectList">
            <ul>
                <li ng-repeat="option in options track by option.id" ng-click="selectOption(option)">{{option.x}} <span ng-if="option.y">({{option.y}}mm)</span> [{{option.z}}] </li>
            </ul>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

I have no idea what I'm doing wrong.

Comment: Hi ..from what i ca see ... you're Declaring it as FILTER .. so you can use it as filter and NOT as directive (you habe to declare and use it ad .directive() )

Comment: But I AM using at as a filter. I'm passing the filtered options to my directive. Sorry for not making that clear - just edited my post accordingly.

Comment: Could we see the directive?

Comment: Just added it to my initial post.

Comment: I'm still too bad to find out what's wrong ahah. Upvoted your post though

Comment: Please add a working code example [(Plunkr)](http://plnkr.co/edit/JricOqES7xsZoVWWAXXd)